# LABVIEW: How to program the following situation?

Tags: labview

There is a crossing sensor at point A for a bicycle. When the bicycle passes point A(the sensor senses the object and then does not), a light turns on for 20 seconds. If the bicycle goes in reverse now and passes through point A again nothing must happen.(Again the sensor only senses something and then it doesn't once the car passes.)

The difficult part of this is that the sensor changes from true to false very quickly because the bicycle moves away. If the bicycle stayed on the sensor; it would be easier. Another difficulty is the way back because it also doesn't stay.

Any propositions? I would appreciate any help. Note My skills in labview are quite mediocre. Though I would like to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two sensors at Point A, one in front of the other, would give you the bicycle direction which would allow you to determine when the bicycle is in reverse.  This assumes that the sensors have a read response fast enough to distinguish between the front and back sensor.

Comment: The sensor doesn't need to distinguish the way the bicycle comes back. The cyclist can turn around and come back. It doesn't need to move backwards like car.

Comment: Your original question stated "If the bicycle goes in reverse now and passes through point A again nothing must happen." Using two sensors would allow you to infer the direction. With a single sensor, you cannot infer direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible.

The only solution I can think of would require that the reverse and forward speeds of the bicylce are different.

If their speeds are different you can try making a determination based on how long the sensor is activated.

However, you run into the problem where all bicyclists may not pass the sensor at the same speed.

The best solution would be to use two sensors and check what order they are activated in.